# DLRS Not Recognizing AccountId Field on CampaignMember Object

Tags: roll-up-summary, dlrs

I'm trying to create a rollup using the DLRS tool where all the campaign names are concatenated in a free text field on the Account. However, the DLRS tool isn't recognizing the AccountId field on the Campaignmember object I get the below error. Any idea why this would be happening? I also have Accounts enabled as campaign members.

[image]

Comment: what api version is DLRS running at ? it uses SobjectDescribe to locate fields on the Object.  AccountId (not documented in the Object Reference) may not exist for that DLRS version. You can use LeadOrContactId when value starts with 001 though

Comment: There is no direct relationship between Campaign and Account, Have you created a custom lookup? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm

Comment: @amitghadage - per the doc, you are right; but the field AccountId exists - I just verified it after enabling the Account as Campaign Members feature

Comment: @cropredy my version is 2.12 It seems like LeadOrContactId works however I'll need a way to set the Relationship criteria to filter for only IDs that start with 001 it seems like. How would I go about updating the DLRS?

Answer (score 0):

The CampaignMember object doesn't have a field AccountId as you can see in the [doc reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm?q=campaignmember)

However, if you enable `Accounts as Campaign Members` in Seetup, the `AccountId` field does appear in the schema (you can check this in Workbench or by simply using the Query Editor in your IDE or Developer Console `SELECT AccountId FROM CampaignMember`

The reason DLRS can't see the field depends on what version of DLRS you are using as it relies on the API version of its code that calls the object's describe

You stated in the comments that you are using DLRS 2.12

Looking at the [DLRS release notes](https://sfdo-community-sprints.github.io/DLRS-Documentation/Changelog/) , I can see that DLRS 2.12 used API version something older than V50.  Accounts as Campaign Members came out in Spring 21 (v51.0)

### Your options

**Option 1** - Update to the latest DLRS 2.17 which is V51.0; the upcoming V2.18 looks like it will be V57

**Option 2** use the field `LeadOrContactId` as the Relationship Field and set Relationship Criteria to be `Is_Account_As_Campaign_Member__c` where that formula field is defined as `NOT(ISBLANK(AccountId))` or, if you prefer, `LEFT(LeadOrContactId,3) = '001'`

Note, you could also avoid the formula field altogether and use this Relationship Criteria:

```
LeadOrContact.Type IN ('Account')
```

although I have not tried polymorphic WHERE clauses in DLRS before